# How can i remove <div> tag from variable without using strip_tags?

Tags: php, regex, html

Here is my code

```
$str="<div>this is the variable</div>";
```

I want to remove its html tag `<div>` without using strip_tags. 
I need `$str="this is the variable"`
Because my server is not working with strip_tags.
I know it is possible with preg_replace. but i dont know regex. 
So please suggest me the solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless you are using PHP 3 (which I hope **noone** is), then `strip_tags` should work....

Comment: `$str = preg_replace("<div>", "", "<div>this is the variable</div>");
$str = preg_replace("</div>", "", "<div>this is the variable</div>");`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @TWCrap NO, don't!
$str = preg_replace("</?div>","",$str);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$s = "<div>this is the variable</div>";
echo preg_replace("/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/", "$1", $s);
// this is the variable
```

<sub>And of course, don't parse HTML with regex :-)</sub>

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/cBloy)**.

Comment: Thnx Joa Silva for answer. but its amazing to me that your code is working good on my local but not on my server. And i also dont understand "And of course, don't parse HTML with regex"

Comment: @KrishnaKarki: It's generally not advisable to use regex to parse HTML; it's usually better to use an HTML Parser. However, if you just want to extract the text between that `div`, and it has a *static* structure, it's fine to use a regex. Having said that, it's strange that works locally and not on your server. Are you sure the string is the same?

Comment: yes string is the same. I just copied your code and pasted to my project for testing first.

Comment: @KrishnaKarki: What are you doing with the result in your production code? `echo`ing it? Saving it in a variable, i.e., `$result = preg_replace(...)`? Are the PHP versions the same?

Comment: I m echoing the variable. and my PHP Version is 5.2.17

Comment: error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
this is my error reporting setting. but there is no error

Answer (score 10):

This variant works also if the DIV tag contains attributes:

```
$str = '<div id="some_id">this is the variable</div>';
$str = preg_replace('/\<[\/]{0,1}div[^\>]*\>/i', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: $str = preg_replace('/^\<[\/]{0,1}div[^\>]*\>/i', '', $str); use ^ so that it will remove only the first div

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove the tag around your text and keep the other tags use:

```
$node = new DOMDocument();
$str = $node->loadXML($str)->firstChild->textContent;
```

WARNING: this will remove the **first wrapper tag** only

and this parses HTML as a markup, which it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$str="<div>this is the variable</div>";
$str = preg_replace('/<(.*?)>/i', '', $str);
```

that would remove all html tags, not only `<div>`

Answer (score -1):

If you're only after a div tag like this you could try

```
preg_replace("</?div>","",$string);
```

of course somebody will probably mention [not to parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
preg_replace("#<div>(.*?)</div>#s", "$1", $s);
```

`s` - a DOTALL modifier, makes `.` match line break characters.

`#` - regex delimiters different from `/`, and thanks to them, there is no need escaping `/`.

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <div>                    '<div>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character (0 or more times, the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  </div>                   '</div>'
```

The `$1` is a **backreference** to the text captured with the first group inside parentheses.