# remove the wrapping of text widget or <div class=“textwidget”></div>

Tags: wordpress

When I write a quote in the text widget and displayed the text is wrapped as...

`<div class="textwidget">My text...</div>`.
I would like to remove the div and put simply "My text...".

**For Example:**

*Current output*

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="textwidget">
       My text...
   </div>
</div>
```

*Required output:*

```
 <div class="container">
     My text...
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**jQuery** way :

```
$('.textwidget').contents().unwrap();
```

---

**PHP** way :

```
$s = '<div class="textwidget"><div class=“textwidget”>My text...</div></div>';
echo preg_replace( '/<div class="container">(.*?)<\/div>/' , '$1' , $s);
```

**Ref :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/12495139/622813

---

So **Wordpress** way : *(Hacks way)*

**Functions.php** *(get dynamic_sidebar as `return`)*

```
function get_dynamic_sidebar($i = 1) {
   $c = '';
   ob_start();
   dynamic_sidebar($i);
   $c = ob_get_clean();
   return $c;
}
```

**Your template :** *(So replace it)*

```
echo preg_replace( '/<div class="textwidget">(.*?)<\/div>/' , '$1' , get_dynamic_sidebar('sidebar_smlinks') );
```

Comment: it works! but is there other way without using jquery like adding some code in functions.php

Comment: Oh sorry, i doesnt read your tag :D, @shellysaju can you show me your PHP function ?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @shellysaju EDITED

Answer (score -1):

Could you please check below code?

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( ".container .textwidget" ).removeClass( "textwidget" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you remove class?

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

It works in **jQuery**, give it a try.

```
var html = $(".container").contents(); 

$(".container").replaceWith(html);
```